# AppleScript; How do I run tell command when a specific text within a folder exists?

Tags: applescript, command-line, script, search

I just learned how this coding thing works today so bare with me if I go all noob on you & feel free to put me in my place for which I'm misinformed; tell me what's up ;)

I have made a .app that quits an application (Spotify), reactivates it, and then plays  the song. However, I feel its possible to go a step further (as it always is) and have the Script run itself when finding `"https://adeventtracker.spotify.com/monitoring?"` in the cache folder

Here is my (first ever) Script:

```
set felicia to "Spotify"
#felicia Is Born

tell application felicia to quit
# #Bye felicia (Spotify)

repeat until application felicia is not running
    delay 0.5
end repeat
#Ensures Spotify is fully closed

repeat until application felicia is running
    tell application felicia to activate
end repeat
#Reactivates Spotify with certainty

if application felicia is running then
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process felicia
            set position of window 1 to {0, 25}
            set size of window 1 to {700, 605}
            delay 1.5
            keystroke {space}
        end tell
    end tell
end if
#Oh. hello, Falicia.
```

the line of text im looking for would be within `/Library/Caches/com.spotify.client/Browser/9d317c60117b0a96ef0f6c80add295d6d50e1342/Cache`. It contains documents that are constantly generating, however, I would only need the newest document to be checked (perhaps by 'Date Modified'? It's Only My Third Day Out Here Idk)
*Theres about 15 documents being made a minute; Im not sure if this would be hard on my CPU, but you might :P*

any attempt/idea to find the solution is welcomed and appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the name of the file ("document" in your terms) you want to check for?

Comment: thanks for the reply! theyre like numerical and alphabetical soup. For example one will be "5f73jrn43..." & "4f7ab9...". If this is an issue perhaps I can try to find a different pattern within its folders.

Comment: Well, if there is no clear and recognizable name it will be difficult to look for it :-) But what is your goal here, do you want just to play a sound whenever a user visits a specific web page?

Comment: My main goal is to have the Application reboot when an advertisement plays because when they do play, it will just freeze and load the time but never register it as complete until I quit the app and run it again

Comment: They're always <30sec not sure if that could be factored. Im reading into it but code goes in one eye and out the other most times lol.